# Examples of drop in R

Tags: r

How does `drop(df)` and `df[which1, which2, drop=T]` work? I can't find any examples...

What I tried:

```
> df = data.frame(a = rep(3,3), b = rep(3,3))
> df$a = as.factor(df$a)
> df$b = as.factor(df$b)
> 
> drop(df)
  a b
1 1 3
2 2 3
3 3 3
> 
> df[,]
  a b
1 1 3
2 2 3
3 3 3
```

Didn't drop anything (line 3 and column b both have one level). Any help's appreciated. Thanks.

---

update: Thanks @Paul Hiemstra

I realize it doesn't drop repeating data, but drops redundant dimensions

```
> df[1, ]
  a b
1 1 3
> dim( df[1, ] )
[1] 1 2
> 
> df[ ,1]
[1] 1 2 3
Levels: 1 2 3
> dim( df[ ,1] )
NULL
```

In above example, it seems R can't make `df[1, ]` a vector because there're columns a and b making the distinguish.
R can make `df[ ,1]` a vector (dim=NULL)

Comment: did you read the documentation about `drop` before using it?

Comment: read https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/drop.html and didn't get it. i'm sorry...

Comment: What do you want to accomplish on the `data.frame`? Please provide us what the output should be.

Comment: @PaulHiemstra I see some source code using it when subsetting data, and wonder what it does...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the documentation of `drop`:

> Delete the dimensions of an array which have only one level.

So, given the following matrix with just one column:

```
m = matrix(1:10, 10, 1)
```

Drop reduces this to:

```
drop(m)
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

which is a vector.

So generally, `drop` drops a dimension of an array or matrix if it has a length of one and effectively is redundant.

For its use in `df[, drop = TRUE]` I quote the documentation of `?'['`:

> drop
>   For matrices and arrays. If TRUE the result is coerced to the lowest possible dimension (see the examples). This only works for extracting elements, not for the replacement. See drop for further details.

For `data.frame`'s, drop has a similar effect: a `data.frame` of one column reduces to a vector.

Comment: Can you provide an example @bergant?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help @Paul Hiemstra! I did some test and it seems to work with data.frame sometimes, see updates in OP please

Comment: @bergant edited my answer to reflect your remark, thanks.